# Flatten json column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I got below Pandas DF with one column as json text.

I wanted to flatten this with all attributes of json text as column

pd.df

```
startTime   endTime recordCount columns
2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z    2021-03-15T23:50:00.000Z    54692   {"format":"0.###","name":"TenMin - SamplerOnOff","baselineType":"ABSOLUTE","baseTime":"D[Z]","aggregate":"NONE","id":"57e23efcbe8817195f117aea","units":"","renderType":"VALUE","dataType":"NUMBER"}
```

wanted result something like below, but in all on row:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the json please? Also recommend you use pandas.read_json()

Comment: i got this working as : dfheader.join(dfheader['columns'].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns='columns')